# How to save a file to y4m out of Matlab?

Tags: matlab, video

So, I've got a movie in the Matlab movie format (Really, just several RGB frames) and I'd like to save it out as a y4m file. (to use with x.264). I've got all the information I need to write the frame header thing at the beginning, and I've got functions that convert the RGB frame to YUV, but any time I try to save it out, it's sideways and the tracking is off. I'm also trying to convert it to C420. Here's my function, currently:

```
function saveMovToY4m(mov, fileName, f, width, height, fpsNum, fpsDen, inter, ascNum, ascDen)

fileId = fopen(fileName, 'w');
fprintf(fileId, 'YUV4MPEG2 W%d H%d F%d:%d I%c A%d:%d C420jpeg\n', width, height, fpsNum, fpsDen, inter, ascNum, ascDen);
for frame = 1:f-1
    frame
    imgRgb = frame2im(mov(frame));
    imgYuv = (convertRgbToYuv(imgRgb, width, height));
    fprintf(fileId,'FRAME\n');
    % Print Y component
    buf = reshape(imgYuv(:,:,1),width*height,1);
    buf = buf;
    fwrite(fileId, buf, 'uint8');

    % Print U component
    Cb = reshape(imgYuv(:,:,2),width*height,1);
    CBdown = downsample(Cb, 4);
    fwrite(fileId, CBdown, 'uint8');   

    % Print V component
    Cbr = reshape(imgYuv(:,:,3),width*height,1);
    CBrDown = downsample(Cbr, 4);
    fwrite(fileId, CBrDown, 'uint8');
end
fclose(fileId);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the "sideways"(I assume you mean rotated) you just need to rotate your array(swap the columns with the rows). For the tracking, if it is off by a fixed amount it seems it has to do with your reshaping(try (width - 1)*height and see what that does and go from there)

Comment: Changing the reshaping throws an error, because it says it can't change the number of elements.

Comment: Rotating the Y component got it very close to correct. It's just got color errors.

Comment: Actually, it's now mirrored. (And mostly black and white.)

Comment: Maybe post an image of the before and after? On the rotation you have to do it a special way so you are not rotating the color information. The tracking is something wierd with the array/vector. I would play around with it to figure out what is going on.

Comment: I've got it oriented the correct way now, but the color's still not right. It's black and white with a bit of purple splashed about. I think it's just a matter of my conversion from RGB to YUV, now. I'll play around with that.

Comment: You might have to rotate the color components too depending on how it's rotating. Basically each (x,y,c) needs to become (y,x,c) but it seems somehow c is being transformed in the rotation which is throwing off the colors.